# r shiny server create vector from inputs to use for subsetting dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, user-input, reactive-programming, shiny-server

```
server <- (function(input, output, session){
  s1m <- reactive({c(input$s1m1,input$s1m2,input$s1m3)})

  library(stringdist)
  result <- responses[which.max(apply(responses,1,function(vec,dat){sum(vec==dat)},s1m)),]

  output$result <- renderUI(result)
})
```

I need to specifically create a character vector "s1m" with the 3 different user inputs s1m1,s1m2,s1m3 so that it can be used to subset my dataframe "responses".

The error I got is 
Error in vec == dat : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

and I think it is because s1m is wrapped by reactive() and it is not considered a vector. So my question is how do I coerce it into a vector or is there any other way to create a vector with user inputs?

Thank you all so much!!

Comment: make sure to specify `s1m()` instead of `s1m`, where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create reactiveValues as below. I did not test this, but alternatively you can also wrap them into a dataframe or list.

```
server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  s1m <- reactiveValues({
    c(input$s1m1, input$s1m2,input$s1m3)
  })

  library(stringdist)
  result <-
    responses[which.max(apply(responses, 1, function(vec, dat) {
      sum(vec == dat)
    }, s1m())), ]

  output$result <- renderUI(result)
})
```

Comment: I used reactiveValues instead of reactive and s1m() instead of s1m and I got

Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

How can i go about this? I can only use a charactor vector for subsetting and not a list or df

Comment: update your question with `sample data` and `u`i and `server` codes. If I don't have the same data you are using it is hard to replicate.